# create additional validation on the form registers the default laravel

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5

This users(mstanggota) table:

```
 Schema::create('mstanggota', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('no_anggota',10);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Mstbeasiswas table:

```
Schema::create('mstbeasiswas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('no_anggota',10)->unique();
            $table->string('nm_anak',25);
            $table->string('kt_lahir',25);
            $table->date('ttl');
            $table->String('nm_skl',50);
            $table->String('st_pend',6);
            $table->String('lbg_pend',6);
            $table->String('prov_skl');
            $table->String('jenkel',9);
            $table->integer('k_umum');
            $table->integer('k_khusus');
            $table->integer('score')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
            $table->string('ket',250)->nullable();
            $table->string('img1',50)->nullable();
            $table->string('img2',50)->nullable();
            $table->string('img3',50)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I would like to make an additional validation. If no_anggota does not exist on table mstbeasiswas then the user cannot register, what is there that could help me? :(

register form view-> [image]

Comment: Yes, you can. See the Validation chapter of Laravel Document  https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: thnks a lot,   but I want to try with ajax, what other references? :(

Comment: Yes, Laravel works fine with traditional request and AJAX as well. I've answered. Check that.

Comment: Have the question been solved or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel surely works fine with no matter which way you've chose. Both traditional request and AJAX request are accepted.

You can make your validation in controllers or creating another class. I prefer the second one in this situation to avoid let controller terrible and unclear.

I assume you've read [the chapter of Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation).

### 1. making a class by artisan command

```
$ php artisan make:request UserRegisterRequest
```

### 2. editing validation rules (change with yours)

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:10',
        'nickname' => 'required|max:20',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'permission' => 'required|numeric',
    ];
}
```

### 3. set names for each field (change with your language)

```
public function attributes ()
{
    return [
        'name' => '姓名',
        'nickname' => '綽號',
        'email' => 'E-Mail',
        'password' => '密碼',
        'permission' => '權限',
    ];
}
```

### 4. response if error

```
public function response(array $errors) {
    return response()->json([
        'status' => false,
        'errors' => $errors
    ]);
}
```

### 5. validate each request before getting in the controller

```
public function account_add(UserRegisterRequest $request) {

    // pass the validation
}
```

The difference between traditional request and AJAX is that you can return `redirection with errors` or `JSON`. In this case, we've chose `JSON` instead of redirection. So that you can handle your errors at front-end.